# How i can solve QMYSQL driver issues compiles with MiniGW64 and MVSC2017?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, compiler-errors, mingw32

I installed Qt 5.14.2 open source and i haven't obvyously QMYSQL driver.
I installed a database Mariadb 10.3 32 bit for my test.
So i followed instructions to compile it. I have two compiler : MinGw32/64 bit and MVSC2017.
With MinGw32 all it was ok.
With MinGW64 it was ok but when i build my QT app i had these messages:

```
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw730_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Program Files (x86)\MariaDB 10.3\lib\mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-win32\lib/libmysql.lib when searching for -llibmysql
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw730_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Program Files (x86)\MariaDB 10.3\lib\mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-win32\lib/libmysql.dll when searching for -llibmysql
```

With MSVC2017 when i begin my building from Console it wrote:

```
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Output:
===================
===================
Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
```

I tried with MYSQL CONNECTOR C 6.1(32/64) and 8.0(64) with same results.
I found a Git Repository with all version compiled but i'd like to understand these issues to solve it in my future.

Comment: ***Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?*** Did you run this from the Visual Studio 2017 command prompt with the compiler environment setup for you?

Comment: Yes i suppose to not setup my enviroment, but i don't know how to setup it. And i haven't start visual studio, i have only download compiler mvsc2017

Comment: Well after you install Visual Studio 2017 (why not 2019?) it should install shortcuts on the start menu that create a command prompt with the variables setup for the compiler.

Comment: I no longer have 2017 installed on any pc I have access to. Here is the command that the shortcut runs in 2019: %comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"

Comment: As for the mingw part, you can't use 32-bit libraries in a 64-bit build. Get or compile a 64-bit libmysql.lib+dll.